# Spark DataFrame add Column with Rows

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

What is the best way to add a new column and new rows to a DataFrame?
Is it possible to do this at the same time?

For example, I have a table AB like:

```
+------+-------+
|     a|      b|
+------+-------+
|  true|   true|      
|  true|  false|   
+---+---+------+
```

Now I would like to add a new column "c" to AB and new rows, but only if a condition is met.
This condition should applied for each row in AB included c=false and c=true.

Let **`foo(row): Boolean`** be the condition and:

```
foo(Row(true, true, false)) = true
foo(Row(true, true, true))  = true 
foo(Row(true, false, false)) = true 
foo(Row(true, false, false)) = false
```

So the new Table ABC should looks like:

```
  +------+-------+-------+
  |     a|      b|      c|
  +------+-------+-------+
  |  true|   true|   true|      
  |  true|   true|  false|      
  |  true|  false|  false|   
  +------+-------+-------+
```

I tried to crossjoin and filter:

```
 val rows = List(Row(true), Row(false))

 val C = spark.createDataFrame(
     spark.sparkContext.parallelize(rows),
     StructType(List(StructField("c", BooleanType)))
 )

 val ABC = AB.join(C).filter(r => foo(row))
```

The perfomance is **very** bad (can you tell me why?). I also tried with flatMap:

```
      val encoder = RowEncoder(AB.schema.add(StructField("c", BooleanType)))

      val ABC = AB.flatMap { row =>
        Seq(Row.fromSeq(row.toSeq :+ true), Row.fromSeq(row.toSeq :+ false)).filter(r => foo(r))
      }(encoder)
```

The performance is also bad. It takes too long for the casting for large tables. As I have noticed, the casting is applied at the masternode. For large tables (million of rows) it performs bad.

Do you have some other and better solutions for this problem?

Btw, I'm using Apache Spark 2.0.1 with Scala.

Comment: I honestly don't understand what you are asking for. And for the record cross joins always have bad performance unless you are using hashing techniques like LSH.

Comment: I would like to expand a boolean table with a new column and new rows. my old table can have 2^n rows and the new table 2^(n+1) rows (n = |columns|). For large n, there are to many rows. So I would like to filter some rows out with the function "foo".

Answer (score 1):

I think you've made it more complicated than it needs to be, from what I understand, the following should yield the result you're after

```
val stuff = List[Row](Row(true, true),Row(true, false),Row(false, true), Row(false, false))
val rows = sc.parallelize(stuff)
val schema = StructType(StructField("a", BooleanType, true) :: StructField("b", BooleanType, true) :: Nil)
val frame = spark.createDataFrame(rows, schema).withColumn("c", col("a")&&(col("b")))
```

then if you do a `frame.show` it should show

```
+-----+-----+-----+
|    a|    b|    c|
+-----+-----+-----+
| true| true| true|
| true|false|false|
|false| true|false|
|false|false|false|
+-----+-----+-----+
```